# How check missed fields with parse_obj_as?

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to check response with Pydantic
For example this in response from API:

```
response = {"id": 1, "pamagite": "please"}
```

Pydantic class:

```
class Pamagite(BaseModel):
    id: int
```

If check response like this:

```
parse_obj_as(cls, response.json())
```

I will miss field **pamagite**
How I can check missed field in Pydantic class?

Answer (score 1):

You can check **obj.**fields_set**** to see whether the value was missing or not.
Example:-

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Foo(BaseModel):
    first: Optional[int] = None
    second: Optional[int] = None

foo = Foo.parse_raw('{"first": null}')

assert foo.first is None and foo.second is None
assert foo.__fields_set__ == {"first"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether you successfully parsed the `pamagite` field in the response, Just add it to your class definition

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, parse_obj_as, ValidationError, StrictStr

response = {"id": 1, "pamagite": 'please'}
response1 = {"id": 1}
response2 = {"id": 1, "pamagite": 222222}

class Pamagite(BaseModel):
    id: int
    pamagite: StrictStr

try:
    parse_obj_as(Pamagite, response)
    print('No Errors')
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)
```

There will be `No errors` for response but Pydantic will throw Validation error `value_error.missing` for response1 and `type_error.str` for response2

You need to use `StrictStr` because Strings, bytes, or floats will be coerced to ints in Pydantic.